# Cassandra map data types in where clause

Tags: dictionary, cassandra, cql3

I'm new to cassandra, so this may be a trivial question.

Given a table defined as follows:
create table Users (
  username text,
  props map,
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

Can I use individual elements of the map in a where clause? (i.e. select * from users where props['is_online']='no';)

I've seen examples referencing individual elements on updates and deletes, but haven't been able to find anything regarding usage as part of the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing collections is not supported until 2.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4511